# RedGate loading oracle tables metadata fails

Tags: oracle, redgate, red-gate-data-compare

I’m using Redgate *Data Compare for Oracle 5*. I’ve (successfully) created Source and Target connections (both Oracle 11g), defined schema names on both side, then switched to *"Tables & Views"* tab. There was Initializing process popped-up, like connecting to db, populating metadata from oracle tables etc. and get list of tables from both connections. Later, I switched back to “main” screen *"Data Sources"* and changed one of the connections to another database (Oracle 12c). This time *"Tables and Views"* initialization failed with bunch of ORA errors.

> ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
>  ORA-29913: error in
>   executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
>  ORA-29400: data cartridge
>   error
>  KUP-04040: file PSImetalsParameters.csv in TEST not
>   found
>  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 288
>  ORA-06512:
>   at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 237
>  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN",
>   line 280
>  ORA-06512: at line 1

(I have doubt that it may be some privileges issue for that user/schema. But not sure which Oracle tables or schemas RedGate needs to access.)
Any help on it?

Comment: There is another team here that have RedGate version 4, and they can connect to that same Db with Oracle 12c and get all tables and views. But those who have version 5 there is the same issue as mine. So, seems it's a RedGate issue.

Comment: Just have found out how to get a logs from RedGate: Right click on the Redgate window at the very top place (along window title). You'll get context menu items with Minimum Log Levels: and you can choose Verbose, Warning, Error or No Logging options. Helped me to go through some details deeply.